# How can I ensure a continuous look and feel using Dynamics CRM 2011 and IFRAME

Tags: css, user-interface, dynamics-crm-2011

I am new to dynamics integration and as a learning exercise I have set up a new server and created an IFRAME in my Account form to display a page from another application (there is mapping between the CRM account and the other application).

This all works great and hats off to Microsoft for making this so simple!

My issue is I want to provide a continuous look and feel to the external application so it looks integrated as much as possible.

At the moment, I only have a grid showing a list of records but this will probably grow to having buttons and input fields too.

I toyed with the idea of just replicating all the CSS using the SDK style guide as a reference but wanted to ask if there is a best/recommended practice for doing this before I went ahead with this tedious task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the same question as you. Having looked around it appears that for the moment you should replicate the styles you need from the style guide in your own resources.

Found this that makes it sound like they are working on something in the future: https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/0ef93ddc-afda-40f3-bb86-9e9e60bb0dc0